# MongoDB: How to update a nested array value after checking if greater than zero?

Tags: mongodb

I'm able to decrease a value in a nested array, but I want to check that the value is greater than zero (so never go to the negative numbers). For example, I have this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
  "slots" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ",
        "number" : 5.0
    }, 
    .......
    .......
    {
        "id" : "VfB4f8G1KcgRA8qx0aby5nI0",
        "number" : 0.0
    }]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839ag"),
"slots" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "V2qlAEEESbrEB4bwberbResbd",
        "number" : 10.0
    }, 
    .......
    .......
    {
        "id" : "DFwseEb5enRbfsbre54rtFfds",
        "number" : 1.0
    }]
}
```

If I want to decrease the `number` value of the first document `[id=5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af]` of the `slots.id = V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ`, I use:

```
db.getCollection('schedulers').update(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
    "slots.id" :"V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ"
},
{
    "$inc":{"slots.$.number":-1}
})
```

But I don't know how to check if the `number` is greater than 0 before decrease the value. I tried to use The filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]`, but I have an error:

```
db.getCollection('schedulers').update(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
    "slots.id" :"V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ"
},
{
    "$inc":{"slots.$[elm].number":-1}
},
{
    arrayFilters: [ { "elm.number": {"$gt" : 0}} ]
})
```

The error is:

**cannot use the part (slots of slots.$[elm].number) to traverse the element....**

Also, apply the condition in the first part of the query doesn't fix the problem, cause mongo traverses all the array, so also if the `number` is zero it simply move to another element in the array until it finds number > 0 and when it finds it, it starts to decrease the `number` value of another element completely ignoring the two id conditions [because now the `$` then point to another element of the array]:

```
db.getCollection('schedulers').update(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
    "slots.id" :"V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ",
    "slots.number":{"$gt" : 0}
},
{
    "$inc":{"slots.$.number":-1}
})
```

I think the correct way to obtain what I want is to use the `arrayFilters` but I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: You are missing [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) which compares every element in the array for multiple conditions.Something like in the query condition `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
    "slots" :{$elemMatch:{"id":"V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ",
    "number":{"$gt" : 0}}}
}` This will only update a single matching element where element has the both id and number value greater than 0

Comment: Works! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using:

```
db.getCollection('schedulers').update(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3b0bd69c0000c2a1d839af"),
    "slots" :
    {
        "$elemMatch":
        {
            "id":"V2qlAEk7Wp0tWwlyWSfX7KRZ", 
            "number":
            {
                "$gt" : 0
            }
        }
    }
},
{
   "$inc":
   {
       "slots.$.number":-1 
   }
})
```

Thanks